# Loading function in ng-init for each ng-repeat doesnt assign return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a two tier table I wish to add values to. The table is loaded dynamically and when each text box is loaded I have called a function sending the item from both ng repeats so that I can check which cells textbox it is and if there exists a value for it add it to the ng-model = result. The function works, however, the returned value does not show in the text box. I don't know what I am doing wrong .. This is the code for my table :

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell" ng-repeat='item in TestingTable[1].EnvironmentTypes'>{{item.Name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow" ng-repeat='item in TestingTable[0].TestingType'>
        <div class="divTableCell">{{item.Name}}</div>
        <div class="divTableCell" ng-repeat="x in TestingTable[1].EnvironmentTypes">
          <input type="text" ng-model="result" ng-init="result = loadData(x, $parent.item)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my javascript code with the loadData function :

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var initial = 0;
  $scope.TestingTable = [{
      TestingType: [{
          Id: 1,
          Name: "Functional Testing"
        },
        {
          Id: 2,
          Name: "Regression Testing"
        },
        {
          Id: 3,
          Name: "Integration"
        },
        {
          Id: 4,
          Name: "BVT"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      EnvironmentTypes: [{
          Id: 1,
          Name: "Dev/QE (VCD)"
        },
        {
          Id: 2,
          Name: "Staging"
        },
        {
          Id: 3,
          Name: "PPE"
        },
        {
          Id: 4,
          Name: "01's"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $scope.Testing = [{
      Id: 1,
      "TestingTypeId": 1,
      TestingType: "Functional Testing",
      EnvironmentTypeId: 1,
      EnvironmentType: "Dev/QE (VCD)",
      value: 100
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      "TestingTypeId": 3,
      TestingType: "Integration",
      EnvironmentTypeId: 1,
      EnvironmentType: "Dev/QE (VCD)",
      value: 98
    }
  ];

  $scope.loadData = function(entype, type) {


    if ($scope.Testing !== undefined) {
      angular.forEach($scope.Testing, function(item) {
        if (item.TestingTypeId === type.Id && item.EnvironmentTypeId === entype.Id) {
          return item.Value;
        } else {
          return initial;
        }
      });
    }
  };

}]);
```

Can someone point out what im doing wrong?

**Update**

Here is the plunker with the code i have so far [click](https://plnkr.co/edit/ysiBbBk2AAHbTF1NIs12?p=preview)

Comment: First you post question about how to make table from your JSON and now you post about filling data :/

Comment: Can i not do that ? @WasifKhan

Comment: @Shayuh You can do that but It's wise to first google the question properly if there is already a solution. Check my answer.

Comment: Yes You can, but first google it and explore it and do some editing in your code. and at last resort use question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @umar I believe this problem couldn't just be googled, I believe OP wouldn't even know what to google. Yes, they could google a bit more about how to properly use ng-init, ng-model and -ng-repeat, but I don't think this was a bad question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are misusing `ng-init`, because since this is being executed inside the `ng-repeat`, every time you are *re-initializing* the `result` model. You should read a bit more about `ng-model`, it would be a nice solution if you had one `Testing` for every combination of `TestingType` and `EnvironmentType`, which is not the case.

Also, your `loadData` function is not returning a value. Those `return` are inside a callback function executed by every iteration of forEach, so they are not returning the loadData function at all.

To fix your code, I just changed `ng-init` and `ng-model` to `ng-value` which I think it's more appropriate for this situation:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="loadData(x, $parent.item)">
```

...and fixed your `loadData` function:

```
$scope.loadData = function (entype, type) {
  var value = 0;
  if ($scope.Testing !== undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Testing.length; i++) {
      var item = $scope.Testing[i];
      if (item.TestingTypeId === type.Id && item.EnvironmentTypeId === entype.Id) {
        value = item.value;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
};
```

That `else` inside your `forEach` was wrong as well, because if the first item matched, the second would enter the `else` block and override the value, that's why I removed that `else` and used a `break`.

I think the code can be improved, but this solves your initial problem.

---

[Here is your plunker fixed.](https://plnkr.co/edit/0Rhe7h98pdqYdERDKcvp?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer and the detailed explanation. Very Helpful. I realised though my returns in the loadData wasnt placed correctly. Totally missed that !

Answer (score 0):

You need to do same as follows

https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>

  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="user in formData.users">
    <label>{{ user.name }}'s Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid">Valid Email Address Required</p>
  </div>

</form>
```

Note how `ng-repeat` is being used

Comment: Please go through the post. It's very well explained. See updated answer..